# Floating-point mantissa and exponent base 2

Tags: python, floating-point, binary, mantissa

I'm trying to understand how to get the mantissa and the exponent in this case. Here's an example I have in my book.

I have this formula `(-1)^s * (1 + M) * b^E-e = x`

```
s = 0 or 1 (the sign)
M = mantissa
b = base (In this case 2)
E = the exponent of this mantissa
e = 127 (for a 32bits system)
```

Still in by book, for ***x*** = 1.602177 * 10^-19, I get

***S*** = 0,

***M*** = 0.4777474,

***E*** = 64

which it works.

*1 * 1.4777474 * 2^-63 = 1.602*10^-19*

However, I don't know how to get the values for ***M*** and ***E***.

I read that ***E*** = log b |x| then ***M*** = |x|b^-E

In this case ***E*** = log2(1.602177*10^-19) = -62.43660 (I'm using a website for the log base 2, so I'm not sure about the result so I tried E = -62 and -63).

***M*** = (1.602177 * 10^-19) * 2^-(-62) = 0.7388737

***M*** = (1.602177 * 10^-19) * 2^-(-63) = 1.4777474

Correct me if I'm wrong but the mantissa is the digits to the right of the floating point. In this case 0.4777474 looks right.

At this point I have ***E*** = -63 and ***M*** = 0.4777474, but ***E*** should be 64

Comment: " In this case 0.4777474 looks right." --> Not precisely.  The fraction portion is a [Dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational), not  0.4777474, but perhaps 4,007,636/(2^23).

Answer (score 0):

> I have E = -63 and M = 0.4777474, but E should be 64

Mathematically, the exponent is -63 as `x = 1.602177 * 10^-19` is in the 2<sup>-63</sup> neighborhood.  Yet the  value stored is a 8-bit unsigned *biased exponent* with [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).  Subtract the bias (-127) from the math exponent to get the biased exponent.

```
biased_exponent = expo - bias
64 = -63 - (-127)
```

Comment: The bias is always -127? I didn't know that. However, for x = pi, the description above doesn't work.

Comment: @proxima There are special considerations when the biased exponent is at min/max.  Review [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) for details.

Comment: I can't find the proper way to find the mantissa. What I did doesn't work for pi.